# how to disable one item in yii2 ActiveFrom dropDownList?

Tags: yii2

Yii2 active form

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'pid')->dropDownList([1=>1,2=>2])->hint('上级分类') ?>
```

I want to disable the option item 2=>2.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 5):

You can add attributes for all items in the dropdownlist with the 'options' key. Let's say you want to disable the second item.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'pid')->dropDownList([1 => 1, 2 => 2], ['options' => [2 => ['disabled' => true]]])->hint('上级分类') ?>
```

In the docs:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#activeDropDownList()-detail

Comment: It's true, but how it's different from my answer? I was one minute faster :)

Comment: thank you ~~ it works. i have read the doc carefully and found the options. but i was puzzled when reading the code. i think yii2 framework code is a little deep.  <?= $form->field($model, 'pid')->dropDownList([1 => 1, 2 => 2], ['options' => [1 => ['disabled' => true]]])->hint('上级分类') ?>

Answer (score 2):

[ActiveField dropDownlist()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activefield.html#dropDownList%28%29-detail) explicitly calls [BaseHtml activeDropDownList()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#activeDropDownList%28%29-detail):

From the docs to `ActiveField` `dropDownList()`:

> The tag options in terms of name-value pairs.
>
> For the list of available options please refer to the `$options`
>   parameter of `yii\helpers\Html::activeDropDownList()`.

And from the docs to `BaseHtml` `activeDropDownList()`:

> `options`: array, the attributes for the select option tags. The array
>   keys must be valid option values, and the array values are the extra
>   attributes for the corresponding option tags. For example,
>
> ```
> [
>     'value1' => ['disabled' => true],
>     'value2' => ['label' => 'value 2'],
> ];
> ```

So pass these options:

```
[
    2 => ['disabled' => true],
],
```

as second parameter to `dropDownList()`.

Answer (score 2):

This would work definitely:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'pid')->dropDownList([1=>1,2=>2], ['options'=>['2'=>['disabled'=>true]]]) ?>
```

Comment: how is it different from the other answers?

Comment: actually i didn't refresh the page and at that time there were no answers. So when i posted my answer i came to know 2 answers were already posted

Comment: Just to inform - even when you don't refresh the page, alert "... answers to the question" appears, you can click on it, and they will load without refreshing the page.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for advice and i apologise too

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$disableDataArr['1'] =  ['disabled' => true];
dropDownList( $dataArr, ['options'=> $disableDataArr ])
```