# Disable Prompt Option Dropdownlist in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I would like to disable the first option from a dropdownlist using yii2 framework. The first option is the prompt one.

```
<?php echo $form->field($kind, 'cod_kind')
                ->label($kind->attributeLabels()  ['cod_kind'] . " (*)")
                ->dropDownList($kind, ['prompt' => 'Select', 'id' => 'cod_kind']);
```

Already tried to do something like this but it did not work, got error exception:

```
->dropDownList($kind, ['prompt' => ['label' => 'Select', 'disabled' => true], 'id' => 'cod_kind']);
```

My question is different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31720718/) because I don't want to disable an available option. I want to disable the prompt option, the option that has the label 'Select'. One more time, already tried the solution of that question with the prompt option and it gave me an error exception.

Comment: What do you mean with disable? You want it to not be present?

Comment: Is it really a good idea? Wouldn't it be better to simply validate that user chose any other option?

Comment: disable like be unable to select the prompt option.

It is validating alright, but I want to do some user-friendly form by unabling the user to select the option 'Select' and show a error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to disable one item in yii2 ActiveFrom dropDownList?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31720718/how-to-disable-one-item-in-yii2-activefrom-dropdownlist)

Comment: It is not duplicaple........ As the question says, already tried the solution from that topic and didn't work because that question is disabling a option value different from the prompt one. When you try that solution with prompt one, it sends you an error exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'class', ['template' => '{input}'])->dropDownList(\yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map($classifiler->find()->all(), 'id', 'name'), ['class' => 'input-custom input-full', 'required' => true,
                        'prompt' => [
                             'text' => 'Select',
                             'options'=> ['disabled' => true, 'selected' => true]
                        ]])->label(false); ?>
```

Comment: Although the code may speak for itself providing some details would help improve the quality of your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up the `required` validator:

```
['cod_kind', required]
```

That's it. On an attempt to choose the prompt option the user will get an error message.